# Is it possible for you to have multiple csv files open at the same time, using the default csv library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using csv files to store data for map cells. i want to know if it is possible to have multiple csv files open at the same time.

 i would like there to be one file of which is a "template", and one where the actual map that will be used is stored.

Ror example (pseudo code):

```
open csv1
open csv2
copy csv1 to csv2
modify csv2
close csv1
close csv2
```

i do not want to use any other libraries like panda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open as many files as your memory can keep-up with.

You can use nested `with` statements.

```
with open('file1.csv','r') as csv1:
    with open('file2.csv','r') as csv2:
        with open('file3.csv','r') as csv3:
            ...do stuff with csv1, csv2, csv3
```

It works as a one-liner as well, but I find it harder to read.

```
with open('file1.csv','r') as csv1, open('file2.csv','r') as csv2, open('file3.csv','r') as csv3:
    ...do stuff with csv1, csv2, csv3
```

Depending on what you want to do with the different files, you have to input the right opening mode 'r','w' etc... check that here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: pardon me for asking, but is this python 3? i don't have much experience with csv, but havent seen "with" used. how does it work?

Comment: Just Google “Python with statement” it is very well documented and quite easy to digest.